# Low settings on flashlights

Tags: flashlights

I have a flashlight, it has a very high lumen output. When it is on high it does not last long.

It does have a "dim" setting. This setting just strobes the led, enough where it does cause headache.

What am I to search for to have a flashlight that does not strobe the led? Maybe one with multiple leds that shut off? Is this a specific type of flashlight?

Comment: Does the light have to be directional? If not, perhaps a lantern would be a better fit. You can find LED lanterns that are very energy efficient and which maintain a charge for much longer than a high-powered flashlight would.

Comment: @JonathanLandrum I did see they have very long-life on low settings, but same issue with flashlights?

Comment: All my headlamps from various brands have a low setting that is advertised to last >24 hours. They are nicely dim for use in a tent in the middle of the night without blinding you or your tent mate.

Comment: @JonCuster they achieve this low output by turning on and off rapidly. It's obvious when using the touch as a bike light in the rain - each raindrop becomes a short streak. It's normally a few kilohertz, far too fast for the human eye, but it sounds like the OP has one that's much slower, whether by design or failure

Comment: @ChrisH - seems likely. I guess my eyeballs just aren’t up to that task.

Comment: go to r/flashlight on reddit or budgetlightforum.com and ask for recommendations on flashlights with no PWM or high frecuency PWM. There are a few people that can still see high frecuency PWM but it's quite rare.

Answer (score 1):

The strobe feature in a flashlight is employed primarily as a deterrent against threats and secondarily as a light signal.

There are several flashlights available that do not include a strobe function and are also reasonably priced. You may get this from any flashlight selling website or Amazon.

Comment: That's a good point.  My take was that the strobing the OP referred to wasn't the deliberate deterrence/signal/special effect that I try to avoid (especially in bike lights), but an inadvertent flashing or flickering in a mode meant to reduce output.  You may be more right than me

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the lamp (flashlight) you bought is either defective or uses older technology.

Many (perhaps even most) LED lamps (flashlights) currently on the market have a bright mode and a dim mode because the bright mode will likely run down the battery/batteries too fast.

Some even have one or more "intermediate" modes in which the brightness is between "bright" and "dim".   Many also offer a strobe mode and/or SOS mode.  All these modes are all distinct.